put the label under a cutted background
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter,ImageEnhance
import pygame,pyautogui
pygame.init()

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("776x582")
window.resizable(0,0)
window["cursor"] = "@NORMAL.cur"

backgroud_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bg.png"))
backgroud = tk.Label(image=backgroud_image)
backgroud.place(anchor=tk.CENTER,x=388,y=261)

#characters vars
    #----> character 1
char1_image1 = Image.open("test.png").convert("RGBA")
brightness1 = ImageEnhance.Brightness(char1_image1)
char1_image1 = brightness1.enhance(0.5)
char1_image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(char1_image1)
char1 = tk.Label(image=char1_image2,highlightthickness=0,borderwidth=0)
char1.image = char1_image2
char1_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("i reseve.mp3")
    #----> character 2
char2_image1 = Image.open("test2.png").convert("RGBA")
brightness2 = ImageEnhance.Brightness(char2_image1)
char2_image1 = brightness2.enhance(0.5)
char2_image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(char2_image1)
char2 = tk.Label(image=char2_image2,highlightthickness=0,borderwidth=0)
char2.image = char2_image2
char2_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("looking for.mp3")
#chatLabel
talk_label = tk.Label(window,bg="black",fg="white")
#characters placing
char1.place(anchor=tk.CENTER,x=233,y=344)
char2.place(anchor=tk.CENTER,x=390,y=187)

#characters function
def charFunction(img,imgForChar,character,brightness,sound,talk):

    def enter(event):
        talk_label.config(text=talk)
        talk_label.place(x=int(character.place_info()["x"])+120,y=int(character.place_info()["y"])+50)
        window["cursor"] = "@HOVER.cur"
        sound.play()
        img = brightness.enhance(0.8)
        imgForChar = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        character.config(image=imgForChar)
        character.image = imgForChar

    def leave(event):
        talk_label.config(text="")
        talk_label.place(x=1000,y=1000)
        sound.stop()
        window["cursor"] = "@NORMAL.cur"
        img = brightness.enhance(0.5)
        imgForChar = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        character.config(image=imgForChar)
        character.image = imgForChar

    character.bind("<Enter>", enter)
    character.bind("<Leave>", leave)

charFunction(char1_image1,char1_image2,char1,brightness1,char1_sound,"i reseve")
charFunction(char2_image2,char2_image2,char2,brightness2,char2_sound,"looking for")



#---------------------------------------------------
window.mainloop()

The background is cutted, so when I put the label under it it fills the cutted shape in the background. How can I place the chars under the background?
This is the bg and I have "char" to put it under it and fill it


you have to better calculate position of your text. Maybe you forgot to add some offset to Y.

better show image with text in wrong place, and image with expected place. And you could use print() to see what you have in variables - maybe you use wrong position.

your img is PIL.Image so you can get img.height and add to position of text if character.place_info()['y'] gives position of top of image, or add img.height//2 if character.place_info()['y'] gives position of center of image.

You cannot see the label under the cut image because the cut image is inside another label and tkinter widget does not have transparent background.  To support transparency, you need to put those images inside a canvas instead.
